# AngularJS type error v2. Is not a function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error, first time it works but second time I get an error. First time it works perfectly.

```
  <table class="table table-bordered bordered table-striped table-condensed datatable"  id="Edii">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Edition Name </th>
                <th>Hight</th>
                <th>Width </th>
                <th>Total Size</th>
                <th>Rate </th>
                <th>No of Insertion</th>
                <th>Total Cost </th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Net Cost </th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="Emp in edi | filter:query">
                <td>{{Emp.Editions}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Hight}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Width }}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Size}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Rate}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Insertion}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Cost }}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Discount}}</td>
                <td>{{Emp.Net}}</td>
                <td><a ng-click="Edition(Emp)" >Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis: if you see urgent begging in a post, feel free to edit it out.

Comment: Ok, I saw it and thought to remove it... now is clear. Next time I will. Thanks for the tip of "editing art".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer, every time when i am populating the table the controller need to be re-initialized so it solved by $state.reload()

thanks